# ios - set uibutton image in interface builder

Tags: image, uibutton

I have few uibuttons in my interface builder, and they all have image value.
I am wondering which method that the IB uses to set the button image. I checked and it's not setImage: forState:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean what method?

Comment: I have bunch of UIButtons that need to be set a different UIImage when highlighted. All of UIButtons are created in IB and set UIImage from there. So I want to customize a method which will set different UIImage when it is highlighted.

Comment: What's wrong with `setImage:forState:`?

Comment: Do you get it? I don't know which method IB calls to set Image for my buttons. So I am asking if you know which method so that I customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you are asking but if you are trying to set the images of a UI Button in the interface builder then select the button and under the attributes inspector there is a section called Image and Background where you can set the image.[image]

If you are trying to change the image once your app is running then implement in your model
`[button setBackgroundImage:(UIImage) forState: UIControlStateNormal];`

Comment: No I mean. I have bunch of UIButtons that need to be set a different UIImage when highlighted. All of UIButtons are created in IB and set UIImage from there. So I want to customize a method which will set different UIImage when it is highlighted. I don't know which method IB calls to set Image for my buttons. So I am asking if you know which method so that I customize it.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this a long time ago, but for the benefit of anybody else finding this question in the future…

I assume that you want to set the images in IB, and not via a method in your code.

The default state is what you see in the sidebar when you select the UIButton

Here is the default state for a UIButton:
[Default state for a UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9V9D.png)

To set the other states, you need to choose the state you want to edit from the "State Config" popup
Here is the Highlighted state for a UIButton:
[Highlighted state for a UIButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WzFr.png)

Enter/choose the name for the image in the alternate states the same way you do for the default state.